# Getting a database error when trying to view data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, database-connection

Alright,

I have a page that interacts with my SQL data connection. it tries to run a stored procedure, but every time I run it, it locks out of the database showing this error:
[image: 1]

Here's the code the fires of the connection and stored procedure `
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images//" + FileUpload1.FileName));
string Image = MapPath("images//" + FileUpload1.FileName);

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BOOKS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddaBook", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTitle.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Image;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAuthor.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublishDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtPublishDate.Text;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                cmd.Connection.Close();

                lblUploadResult.Text = "File uploaded successfully.";
                lblUploadResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;

            }`
```

Any help is appreciated and always thank you!

Comment: You should do a try { } catch { } or search for the lock file associated to verify it is not in use.  But One Drive and SQL Server services can lock those files pretty frequently.  Even antivirus software can lock the file while a scan occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your mdf file out of OneDrive. Sometime when OneDrive is doing an upload, or one of the many other processes it does, it will lock the files - especially from system user.

Comment: Where would I move it to?

Comment: I'm moved the file now i'm getting this error "The database 'C:\BOOK\APP_DATA\DB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 904. This server supports version 852 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'C:\BOOK\APP_DATA\DB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\BOOK\App_Data\DB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that your database is under usage so you can not access it.

Be sure that no other code is accessed in the database `without closing the connection`.

You may also update the code with the following as some not needed lines are removed.

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BOOKS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddaBook", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTitle.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Image;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtAuthor.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublishDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtPublishDate.Text;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    lblUploadResult.Text = "File uploaded successfully.";
    lblUploadResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the file open but just don't know it. For example, if you are trying to open a text file called Test.txt (or conversely a .mdf database file which has already been opened), then you will get this error, which is also why you are likely getting the other errors down the line but all related to this first error.

With databases, things can get a bit tricky, because you can connect to a database and at times get an error and be kicked out of the system without closing the connection or process... at which point a currently running but unknown process may be keeping the connection alive. You can look at all open processes on your system or see if you mistakenly have the connection open and then close it before trying to open it through the application.

Comment: How do you close it?

Comment: Microsoft says, "We strongly recommend that you always close the connection when you are finished using it so that the connection will be returned to the pool. You can do this using either the Close or Dispose methods of the Connection object, or by opening all connections inside a using statement in C#". So this can be done by calling a simple method which goes through several steps to make sure everything is closed properly... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?redirectedfrom=MSDN